# How to install corner bead on an uneven corner

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud, corner-bead

How do I install this corner bead without it buckling when I screw it down. Do I just fill the recessed spot with mud first? If it matters it's the ceiling in my shower.  [image][image]

Comment: Filling with mud, pressing the bead in, screwing up from the bottom, then holding the top down with tape while waiting for the mud to dry sounds like a VeryGoodIdea™. Follow up with a _gentle_ application of screws through the freshly set mud. But I'd wait for someone with more experience/knowledge than me before diving into that plan.

Comment: Thar corner actually looks pretty even to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. That corner is *beautiful* compared to most. Corner bead isn't normally screwed, though, for the reason you've encountered--screws pull way to hard and cause deformation. Use drywall nails (gently) or narrow-crown staples (like for underlayment).

Be sure to keep the bead above the plane of the wall. In the photo, the top side has a slight recess where the edge of the other sheet terminates. Don't pull the bead down tight to that. I like to stand a carpenter's square on the wall surface and lap onto the bead. If the square doesn't have a slim gap under it, shift the bead flange on the adjacent wall face to make it so. Imagine pulling your taping knife down that wall later... you don't want it to scrape the flange.

Comment: I've always used screws for corner bead with out any issues, for this one though nails were a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Get some cardboard drywall shims. They are sold at the big box stores and can be trimmed in either direction to fit your application. You could also try trimming off 1/4" from the whole length of the corner bead.

Comment: Neither of those things are necessary (or even remotely standard).

Comment: If he screws it in as is, the entire edge of that corner bead is going to pop out and almost certainly be proud of the actual corner itself making it impossible to get a good finish. Stapling will probably have the same result. Nails would work better, but I'd still pop a shim under there and avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Prefill or coat the corner with Quick setting mud like EZ Sand 20. Get the corner straight as possible. When dry sand it then nail the bead on. Or get some of the paper-backed bead and mud it on. Make sure you have plenty of mud under the bead and position it straight
and wipe it down pushing the excess mud out but leave enough mud to hold the paper and bead to the wall.